# Setting up hostname domain certificates in AWS private hosted zone

Tags: amazon-ec2, apache-kafka, aws-acm

I am provisioning a 3-broker kafka cluster on AWS EC2, and I need them to be reachable on an internal VPC at URLs like `1.kafka.private.com`, etc. If I do not attach a cert, I know that systems using kafka (and maybe the brokers themselves) will give "SSL Handshake" errors.

I have the cert in ACM for `*.private.com` (that's an example) but I know you cannot attach ACM certs directly to EC2 instances, just loadbalancers and cloudfront.

I set up a similar cluster in a public zone and used letsencrypt certbot to issue certs, but I cannot do that know since this private dns is not publically resolvable.

How can I set this up? I would prefer not to put each of the 3 brokers behind 3 loadbalancers, and I'm not even sure if that would work.

Comment: For private resources, self-signed certificates should be enough. No need for letsencrypt nor acm in this case.

Comment: Do you know if this holds true for eventually converting the certs into a JKS keystore so that kafka can use it?

Comment: Sadly, don't know how it works with JKS.

Comment: @swagrov how did you solve this one? I'm facing a similar issue with elasticsearch.

Comment: @Morariu I switched to using a public route53 zone, and then certbot's route53 DNS can handle the DNS01 challenge.